# ignore event on element with borderradius

Tags: javascript, css

I want to ignore a click/touchstart event on a div with border radius 50% (a circle) when it's not clicked on the visible circle (so when you click on a corner of an div).

I did wrote a really simple function (it's not 100% precise, it's a workaround, for now it's fine) to check if you click on a corner of the div:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zhwri

so far so good,

Problem:

The circle (.circle) will rotate with transform (for example -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); now the function won't work correctly (probably because of the box model etc.) is there any way to figure out whether I have clicked at a corner when the div is rendered with rotation? because the coordinates refers to the box model (I guess) and thats not what a client sees.

Hopefully me question is clear, maybe there are other ways to figure to out then way i suggested in my function?

thanks for the help!

update: i forgot to tell that in this case SVG or Canvas is not an option (pitty :( ), so for everyone who suggest this: you are right, but unfortunately not an option :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use canvas elements, for example with the `d3.js` library http://d3js.org/, it will be much simpler to select complex shapes like circles (and watch for events).

Comment: Yeah, i know, problem is that in this case i cant use canvas or svg, so it needs to be plain html/css(3)/js

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with these statements

```
eToParent['x'] = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX - $(e.target).offset().left;
eToParent['y'] = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY - $(e.target).offset().top;
```

`.offset()` does not take your CSS transformations (i.e., `rotate(45deg)`) into account. So, for your example, you would have to apply the rotation manually to your element's reported offset.

Comment: what do you mean precisely with "apply the rotation manually to your element's reported offset."?

Comment: `$(e.target).offset().left`, for example, would not reflect the true visible offset of your rotated element, so you'd have to take that value and then get the pixel that's 45 degrees (clockwise) from it.

Comment: Thats sounds fair, but how you get the pixel 45 deg (clockwise) of it, because that would be the answer probably?

Comment: I answered the question based on the way I would attempt to go about doing what you're trying to do given the information you posted. I don't actually have the time to dev/test a solution for you. Take my suggestion and see if you can develop a solution to your own problem, and if so, post it as an answer here and mark it correct.

Comment: hmm yeah well, id dont want to be rude or something, i appriciate your input, but what you say is eventually the same as what i allready told and also described. i cant get the actual offset because of the css transform and the the offset/coordinates are calculated by the original render (box model)